# Antlr4 import grammar from path

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Simple questions which I so far think the answer is no:

Is it possible to import grammars from a child directory? e.g.:

```
grammar literals;

import myFolder/IntegerLiterals;
```

with the following structure:

```
/ 
 literals.g4
 myFolder/
    IntegerLiterals.g4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an [ANTLR 4 grammar written in ANTLR 4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/antlr4/ANTLRv4Parser.g4) on the examples repo.

Let's take a closer look:

```
delegateGrammars
    :   IMPORT delegateGrammar (COMMA delegateGrammar)* SEMI
    ;

delegateGrammar
    :   id ASSIGN id
    |   id
    ;

id  :   RULE_REF
    |   TOKEN_REF
    ;
```

So, looks like the answer really is no, as you can't put directory separators in there. The file name must be a valid rule/token name.

Comment: Thanks for linking to the source!

Comment: @Diolor The real source is actually [here, written in ANTLR 3](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/tool/src/org/antlr/v4/parse/ANTLRParser.g). It has an equivalent `delegateGrammars` rule.

Comment: Yep, it's a grammar id not a filename.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found this site but got no solution. After some more googling I found a solution for this problem:

Actually there is now a way how to import grammars from other directories:

Use the -lib option when running antlr to define where your gramars are that you want to import. Here is the docu for the options: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/tool-options.md

So you write your grammar:

```
grammar literals;
import IntegerLiterals;
```

Then you run in command line:

```
antlr4 -lib C:/.../myFolder literals.g4
```

Comment: The previous response pointing out that you import a grammar ID not a file name is correct, and that was probably all that could be said in 2014. But using the -lib flag would be good advice today.